# specify the step of pgfplots axis

Tags: pgfplots

Now the numbers on the x-axis are

> 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2

I want to show integer only:

> 0, 1, 2

How can I do that? My code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=threads,
    ylabel=speedup & deviation]
\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup] {datafile.dat};
\addplot table[x=thread,y=dev] {datafile.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The content of datafile.dat:

```
thread  speedup dev
1   1   0
2   3   1
3   5   0
4   7   1
```

Comment: For example, you can include a compilable *minimal* code and we can have a look together :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to have the `x ticks` to appear exactly as entered you can use the option `xtick=data`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
thread  speedup dev
1   1   0
2   3   1
3   5   0
4   7   1
}\datafile

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=threads,
    ylabel=speedup \& deviation,
    xtick=data]
\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup] {\datafile};
\addplot table[x=thread,y=dev] {\datafile};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or you can enter manually by `xtick={1,2,3,4}` option

Comment: This wouldn't be ideal with large sets of data.

Comment: @Magpie then you use explicit ticks or leave it to pgfplots anyway.

Comment: Or, for instance, you can enter `xtick={0,...,10}`, instead of manually writing the numbers from 0 to 10

Answer (score 49):

If you want to specify the *step*, i.e. the interval of your ticks, you can also use the `xtick distance`-option. Refer to section 4.15 in the [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), Version 1.13. As @Magpie pointed out, this one is easier to use than `xtick` if use have a large number of ticks you want to show.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% example data file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{datafile.dat}
    thread speedup dev
    1 1 0
    2 3 1
    3 5 0
    4 7 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=threads,
        ylabel=speedup \& deviation,
        xtick distance=1
        ]

        \addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup] {datafile.dat};
        \addplot table[x=thread,y=dev] {datafile.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you provide some sample code showing this in action.

Comment: This is a really valuable answer.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer for the original quenstion in most use cases, thanks!

Comment: When I try to run this MWE, I get the following error:

`Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/xtick distance', to which you passed '1', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: If you have a package manager, check if your pgfplots is on version >1.13. If it's not, update it.

Answer (score 15):

Section 4.14 of the [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) describes the `xtick` option, which gives a list of locations for the ticks. In this case `xtick={1,...,4}` should do the trick.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% example data file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{datafile.dat}
thread speedup dev
1 1 0
2 3 1
3 5 0
4 7 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=threads,
    ylabel=speedup \& deviation,
    xtick={1,...,4}]

\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup] {datafile.dat};
\addplot table[x=thread,y=dev] {datafile.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(EDIT: Different section numbers for difference versions of the manual)

Comment: What about axis that go from -4 to 4?

Answer (score 15):

Use `xtick={0, 1, 2}` to specify where you want the `xticks`:

[image]

### Notes:

- This also necessitated specifying `xmin=0` to get the marker for `x=0`.
- You also need to `\&` for the `ylabel`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{datafile.dat}
thread  speedup dev
1   1   0
2   3   1
3   5   0
4   7   1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=threads,
    ylabel={speedup \& deviation},
    xtick={0, 1, 2},
    xmin=0
]
\addplot table[x=thread,y=speedup] {datafile.dat};
\addplot table[x=thread,y=dev] {datafile.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```