# pgfplots: Reduce number of ticks

Tags: pgfplots

I'm doing a histogram with a large number of bins:

```
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar interval,
  ]
    \addplot+[hist={bins=200}] table[y index=0] {FILENAME};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately, pgfplots produces a terribly ugly x-axis where the xticks are printed too close together so that they are overlapping and you can't read a thing.

How can I reduce the number of ticks? For example show only every nth tick.

Comment: You can specify where exactly you want the ticks to go with `xtick={-20,-15,...,20}` or some other pattern.  Please keep in mind that while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Without a sample of `FILENAME` the reproduces this I can not test if this will fix the problem for you.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47345/specify-the-step-of-pgfplots-axis

Comment: xtick doesn't help because the numbers I have are quite high precision: http://pastebin.com/h68WDRZY

Comment: So how many significant digits do you want to display? I think the results with `xtick={0,2,...,12}` with your data produces reasonable results, but perhaps a real expert with plotting will have a better answer for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a histogram with such a large number of bins, `ybar interval` as an `axis` option is not the ideal choice. `ybar interval`, if passed to the axis, will place a label for each bin, and draw a vertical line between each pair of bins; the algorithm usually employed for finding a useful number of labels is not used here. In your case, simply omitting `ybar interval` (or supplying `ybar` instead) in the axis options yields a much better result. Note that the `ybar interval` style is set for the individual plot anyway because you're using `hist`, but as a plot option, it doesn't influence the label placement:

[image]

The plot could be improved a bit by adding vertical grid lines, and choosing `hist/data min`, `hist/data max`, and `hist/bins` in such a way that the bins line up with the grid lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits=false,
    enlarge y limits=upper,
    axis lines*=left,
    xmajorgrids,
    grid style={white,ultra thin},
    axis on top,
    tick align=outside
  ]
    \addplot [
        hist={bins=150, data min=0, data max=15},
        fill=black!75, draw=none
    ] table [y index=0] {data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! I was wondering about the strange labeling as well..