# groupplots: Managing number of ticks

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

This question was asked already [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51358/pgfplots-reduce-number-of-ticks) but not answered completely. I know of two approaches but they do not apply to my problem:

1. `ytick=data`: In my example some of the tick labels will overlap.
2. `ytick={1000,...,6000}`: Defining explicit ticks will cause problems when the data of each plot does not lie within the same range.

So my idea would be somelike the following:

`ytick=NumOfTicks`, whereas `NumOfTicks` can be any integer (e.g. `ytick=5` would generate five ticks for every `nextgrouplot`).

Also interesting (but not applicable to my example) would be to write a macro which allows the following:

`ytick={tickMin,tickMax,tJump}`, whereas `tJump` can be any number (e.g. `ytick={0,10000,2.5}` would generate ticks starting at 0 and ending at 10000 with a space of 2.5 between each tick)

**Note**
Changing the `groupplot`-argument `footnotesize` to any other size (e.g. `small`) also has an impact on the number of ticks when you leave the determination of the number of ticks to LaTeX.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group name=my plots,
            group size=2 by 2,
            xlabels at=edge bottom,
            ylabels at=edge left,
    vertical sep= 1.5cm,
    horizontal sep= 2cm,
%   every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel}
        },
        footnotesize,%changing footnotesize to small will affect the number of ticks
        width=5cm,
        height=5cm,
        %
        xlabel=xlabel,
        ylabel=very long label
%   ,ytick=data
]
    \nextgroupplot[title=\#1]
        \addplot coordinates{(42, 255) (43, 1584) (44, 1296) (45, 432) (46, 972) (47, 540) (48, 1104) (49, 0)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=\#2]
        \addplot coordinates{(42, 400) (43, 400) (44, 0) (45, 400) (46, 0) (47, 0) (48, 0) (49, 0)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=\#3]
        \addplot coordinates{(42, 1800) (43, 2100) (44, 1800) (45, 900) (46, 2100) (47, 2100) (48, 2100) (49, 0)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=\#4]
        \addplot coordinates{(42, 6800) (43, 2800) (44, 2800) (45, 2800) (46, 2000) (47, 2800) (48, 0) (49, 0)};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pgfplots has two parameters which control the selection of default ticks:

1. `max space between ticks`
2. `try min ticks`

The first parameter is the primary parameter, it is used to derive the number of ticks. If this number is below `try min ticks`, pgfplots increases the number.

Note that pgfplots only accepts specific tick locations, depending on the data range. For example, if the data range is [0,1500], if will not select 1250 as tick position (too detailed). If it does not find "suitable" tick positions, it will rather relax the parameter `try min ticks` than to select arbitrary numbers. In your example, it means that you will get either 4 or 5 ticks even though I requested `try min ticks=5`.

The overal solution here could be to set `max space between ticks` to some very huge value in the sense of "ignore this parameter" and force pgfplots to respect only the `try min ticks` argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={
    group name=my plots,
    group size=2 by 2,
    xlabels at=edge bottom,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    vertical sep= 1.5cm,
    horizontal sep= 2cm,
    %   every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel}
},
    footnotesize,%changing footnotesize to small will affect the number of ticks
        max space between ticks=1000pt,
        try min ticks=5,
    width=5cm,
    height=5cm,
    %
    xlabel=xlabel,
    ylabel=very long label
    %   ,ytick=data
    ]
    \nextgroupplot[title=\#1]
        \addplot coordinates{(42, 255) (43, 1584) (44, 1296) (45, 432) (46, 972) (47, 540) (48, 1104) (49, 0)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=\#2]
        \addplot coordinates{(42, 400) (43, 400) (44, 0) (45, 400) (46, 0) (47, 0) (48, 0) (49, 0)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=\#3]
        \addplot coordinates{(42, 1800) (43, 2100) (44, 1800) (45, 900) (46, 2100) (47, 2100) (48, 2100) (49, 0)};
    \nextgroupplot[title=\#4]
        \addplot coordinates{(42, 6800) (43, 2800) (44, 2800) (45, 2800) (46, 2000) (47, 2800) (48, 0) (49, 0)};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, you can only set these parameters for all axes at once. Perhaps they should be configurable for individual axes.

Note that `footnotesize` also changes these parameters (as it ought to do).

Comment: Are there equivalents of `try min ticks` and `max space between ticks` for the x  and y parts?

Comment: These two options are only available once, not per axis.